# DAX measure to count IDs satisfying a threshold condition

Tags: powerbi, dax

```
SalePersonId    Month   Qty
1               Jan-18  5
2               Jan-18  7
1               Feb-18  1
2               Feb-18  8
3               Feb-18  12
```

I need to create a measure which gives me a count of salespersons whose total sales quantity is more than 10 for the year 2018.

The result should be 2 (Sale person 1 & 3)

I can achieve this in T-SQL with the following query:

```
SELECT COUNT(Distinct EmpId) FROM T1 GROUP BY UserId HAVING SUM(Qty) > 10
```

How can I do the same in DAX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one possible approach:

```
= COUNTROWS(
      FILTER(
          SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(
              T1[SalePersonId],
              "Total", SUM(T1[Qty])),
      [Total] > 10))
```

The `SUMMARIZECOLUMNS` part is essentially

```
SELECT SalePersonId, SUM(Qty) AS 'Total' FROM T1 GROUP BY SalePersonId
```

The `FILTER` part is equivalent to the `HAVING` clause and then you just count the rows in the resulting table.